# Как устранить [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:?

Tags: java, maven

Пробовал поставить maven-surefire-plugin.
Потом отказался от этой идеи, но теперь не могу собрать проект. Как избавиться от этого плагина?

ошибка при запуске сборки проекта:

> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1.082 s [INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-08T17:11:31+02:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/429M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project awis_pg_importer: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called? [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefirebooter3488780226193196494.jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire2349496977136427011tmp /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire_08910131109555475702tmp [ERROR] -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project awis_pg_importer: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called? Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefirebooter3488780226193196494.jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire2349496977136427011tmp /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire_08910131109555475702tmp
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called? Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefirebooter3488780226193196494.jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire2349496977136427011tmp /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire_08910131109555475702tmp
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>           ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called? Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefirebooter3488780226193196494.jar /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire2349496977136427011tmp /home/dubravsky/IdeaProjects/123/awis_pg_importer/target/surefire/surefire_08910131109555475702tmp
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:485)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:352)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:158)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:967)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:831)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:729)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>           ... 21 more [ERROR]  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Pom.xml

> http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>       4.0.0
>
> ```
> <groupId>novaposhta</groupId>
> <artifactId>awis_pg_importer</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>
> <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
>     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>     <jdom.version>1.1</jdom.version>
>     <kafka.streams.version>1.1.1</kafka.streams.version>
>     <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
>     <kafka.avro.serializer>5.0.0</kafka.avro.serializer>
>     <apache.avro.version>1.8.2</apache.avro.version>
>     <org.postgresql.version>42.2.5</org.postgresql.version>
>     <com.googlecode.json-simple>1.1.1</com.googlecode.json-simple>
>     <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
> </properties>
>
> <repositories>
>     <repository>
>         <id>confluent</id>
>         <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
>         <version>${jdom.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
>         <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
>         <version>${kafka.streams.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
>         <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
>         <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
>         <version>${kafka.avro.serializer}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
>         <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
>         <version>${apache.avro.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
>         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.postgresql.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
>         <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
>         <version>${com.googlecode.json-simple}</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>${junit.version}</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>
> <build>
>     <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
>     <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/</testSourceDirectory>
>     <resources>
>         <resource>
>             <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
>         </resource>
>     </resources>
>     <testResources>
>         <testResource>
>             <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
>         </testResource>
>     </testResources>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.6.1</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>${java.version}</source>
>                 <target>${java.version}</target>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build> </project>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, видимо переработал :) Плагин должен быть прописан в pom.xml если нужно запускать тесты.